# python scrapy callback is not going when i run it from php

Tags: php, python, scrapy

Python scrapy callback is not going when i run it from php code. Everything works fine, but the callback only not going, don't know why. I'm using the following code, if anybody come across of this please let me know what's the problem. Thanks earlier!

My code:
Php:

```
exec("python mypythoncode.py $input", $my_output);
```

Python:
mypythoncode.py

```
import sys  
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess, CrawlerRunner  
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings  
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging  
from scrapy.settings import Settings  
from tutorial.spiders.MixSpider import MixSpider  
inputURL = sys.argv[1]  

crawler = CrawlerProcess(Settings())
crawler.crawl(MixSpider, inputURL=inputURL)
crawler.start()
```

MixSpider.py

```
import scrapy
import string
from tutorial.items import DmozItem
from urlparse import urlparse
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class MixSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MixSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        url = kwargs.get('inputURL')
        self.start_urls = [url]

    def parse(self, response):
        for slide in response.css('#all > div > div > div > div.slide'):
            title = slide.css('div > div.frame > address > a::text').extract()
            pro_link = slide.css('div > div.frame > address > a::attr(href)').extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(pro_link,meta={'pro_title' : title,'title_link' : pro_link},callback=self.parse_property)

    def parse_property(self, response):
        print "inside"
```